# Extract value from JSON using json parser or regex

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "c": {
        "21969": {
            "name": "TC",
            "status": "completed",
            "result": {
                "count": 421
            },
            "identifier": "column1"
        }
    },
    "analyses": {
        "1": {
            "name": "test",
            "status": "completed",
            "result": {
                "21969": {
                    "status": "completed",
                    "result": {
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "headerName": "RD",
                            "field": "d_c"
                        }, {
                            "headerName": "LN",
                            "field": "l_n"
                        }, {
                            "headerName": "Count",
                            "field": "count"
                        }, {
                            "headerName": "% ",
                            "field": "percent"
                        },  {
                            "headerName": "os",
                            "field": "os"
                        }],
                        "rowData": [{
                            "d_c": "Total",
                            "line_number": 1,
                            "count": 869,
                            "sub_header": true
                        }, {
                            "d_c": "test01",
                            "l_n": "1",
                            "count": 356,
                            "percent": "40.97 %",
                            "os": "17.45"
                        }, {
                            "drug_combo": "test02",
                            "l_n": "2",
                            "count": 61,
                            "percent": "7.02 %",
                            "os": "29.75 (22.88 - 42.48)"
                        }
                         ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want to fetch the count values present only in these two blocks:

```
{
                            "d_c": "test01",
                            "l_n": "1",
                            "count": 356,
                            "percent": "40.97 %",
                            "os": "17.45"
                        }, {
                            "drug_combo": "test02",
                            "l_n": "2",
                            "count": 61,
                            "percent": "7.02 %",
                            "os": "29.75 (22.88 - 42.48)"
                        }]
```

For example I have tried `$count..`  but it gives all the count values e.g. 421,869,356,61
similarly for `$l_n..` gives 1,1,2.
Expected Result: - Want to fetch only 356 and 61 for count. For l_n only wants to fetch 1,1.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your response contains more than one node named "count", you will have to be more precise.

In JMeter, the JSON Extractor allows you specify [Match No.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

> If the JSON Path query leads to many results, you can choose which one(s) to extract as Variables

Alternatively, something like `$.analyses..rowData[1].count` should give you the "count" value for "test01". Similarly `$.analyses..rowData[2].count` should give you the "count" value for "test02".